# Access Denied when trying to install an SSL certification

Tags: java, ssl, cmd, windows-8.1

I wanted to install an ssl certification.
But I got:

```
#9: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5C DE 33 E9 4A ED 08 31   64 1E 0E BE CC 6E AD AB  \.3.J..1d....n..
0010: FD F0 56 C6                                        ..V.
]
]

Trust this certificate? [no]:  y
Certificate was added to keystore
[Storing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1144)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)

C:\Users\Houssem\Desktop\CERTIF_SSL>
```

I have to notice that I run the cmd as **administrator**

**My windows is 8.1**

**UPDATE**: I am also already Administrator

[image]

Comment: Running as an administrator does not necessarily mean running in elevated mode; could that be the issue?

Comment: Of course, Administrator is the highest user level in windows. This worked fine before re-installing the windows

Comment: Problem solved? &
`opinion based` why use Win 8.1 anyway?

Comment: Not yet. I insisted on Windows 8 because it may subject of security updates after last "wannacry" attacks. I used not to face such an issue

Comment: You know the WannaCrypt ransomware targets out-of-date systems? So if you have Win 10 auto update it was easy peasy secure? 
Ok anyway. Sry if I ask: but have you tried pressing Windows+X and then “Command Prompt (Admin)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run as administrator (on linux using sudo command)!
`Access is denied` means you can't acces the file via your normal user.

Comment: *I have to notice that I run the cmd as administrator*

Comment: then what about `java.io.FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: 'Access denied' technically leads to not finding the file.

Comment: What is the output of cacls or icacls on that directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\'  or 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security'

Comment: what is the structure of command to grant full permission? I couldn't understand it(first time to hear about it)

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing the same issue on Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1.